# When is it ok to skip discovery?

Tags: user-research, usability-testing, requirements

I'm working on a project that needs a vast overhaul. Lets just say its Lotus Notes for examples sake.

The product is 5 - 10 years out of date (I've just been brought in). It needs a huge amount of change, I don't need to do any discovery to know that.

Am I supposed to run discovery on every detail or can I just go ahead do an expert review, grab all the low-hanging fruit, call that ground zero and do my normal discovery process from there?

Discovery is supposed to be fast, I've done A/B tests on the current and new work but the board members refuse to accept the x10 improvement.

I'm miffed. Your candid opinions are most welcome either for or against skipping discovery in this case.

Comment: What do you mean by 'discovery' in this sense? Can you explain the process that you're thinking of skipping? (The tag `discovery` as you've used here isn't the one you're discussing so it'll need retagging if `usability-testing` doesn't already cover it)

Comment: I think the Discovery phase is more commonly known as Research.

Comment: I am referring to Discovery as prescribed by Marty Cagan and the Silicon Valley Product Group: [link](http://www.svproduct.com/articles/tag/product+discovery)

It is the process of research, rapid prototyping, testing and iterating to create high value products.

Comment: So by your definition of "discovery" what would be skipped is all activities required to inform the team on a user centered design solution. So is your question more acurately stated "When is it ok to go straight to development?" If so, what would you go to development with?

Comment: So we did an expert review - used all our previous experience to put together a feasible prototype. We tested it and got the turnaround we was looking for. But because we didn't test individual elements we've been told its not valid. So we've not entirely skipped the process but more streamlined it. I understand that doing a wave of changes is not easy to measure but holistically we've seen a big improvement. I would rather push these out for delivery now (because this is less than a 1 or 2 sprints of effort. Then we could investigate which pieces really worked best and iterate.

Comment: @TyFairclough you may be able to help alleviate some of your stakeholder's concerns about individual elements, e.g. Form layout, by bringing up best practices and research others have done to come up with these best practices. It really sounds like a trust issue with a brand new team. Perhaps it might not be a bad idea to ask them right out, given the time constraints what more validation do them need besides external research and go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose everything does need to be changed. But do you know what you are trying to change it to?

Most complex applications existed because the users have very specific needs that made them stick with it despite its shortcomings.

I would see discovery in this case not about the existing application so much as just understanding the user's context. What are they trying to use the software to do and more importantly why.

This is something I would ideally interview actual users and do user shadowing to find out. Your team may have SMEs subject matter experts, but it's much better to confirm what they say with users as a sanity check before you move ahead with idea testing.

It's way less expensive understanding your users beforehand than to come up with ideas that's no where near the mark and you have to try again.

As to how to sell to your stakeholder regarding to how much is enough discovery, it sounds like this is a new process that they're not very familiar with. Try figure out ballpark numbers for how often the area/feature is used. If it's easy for you to get short video/audio clips of a few people you talk to about the issue. Create a quick 5 minute compilation clip and show it to them. That might give it enough of data + emotional push  to get them to see the issue.

After the stakeholders see the problem, ask them to let the team move on to cheap prototypes and test those to confirm the initial findings.

Give them a definite timeline. You can give them the results from the prototype testing in say 2-3 weeks. Looking at the development cycle for most traditional large applications, this period of time is close to nothing.

Comment: Just to clarify users are not sticking to the product. Sales are drastically down year on year. That's why we've been called in. The issue is the rate of change needs to be almost immediate (needed it yesterday) and I'm being blocked from testing multiple changes simultaneously.

I'm looking for some case study or musings from someone who's succeeded in a position such as this to either give the pros or cons for skipping discovery or better put fast tracking it.

Comment: Ah what I've described above is the ideal case where you're given the budget and time. If you don't, then whatever quick hallway testing you can get in, people from other departments acting as surrogate users is better than having nothing. We as experts are fallible. Anything you can get in serves as a sanity check. This matches what you call "fast tracking". And I've done it plenty of times. It's one of the first steps in getting your company to value UX and the discovery process. Highly recommend the book Undercover User Experience Design on this topic. http://undercoverux.com/

Comment: you've made some very interesting points and I appreciate all the input. I'll be picking up the book and looking at ways to build these relationships. We're a remote, distributed team and this has always makes it harder. But your right this is probably having a detrimental impact right now.